# Django models: Create a custom json as a field in an exisiting model

Tags: django, django-models

I have an existing model in **models.py** as follows:

```
class Work(models.Model):
   id = CustomUUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,editable=False, primary_key=True)
   level = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
   is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to add a custom Json field to this model.
The json value is expected to be like this:

`is_experienced_required = {"is_enabled":True, unit:"months", no:10}`

I also want to specify some validations for this field:

1. *is_enabled* should only be a boolean value
2. *unit* should be an enum to select value from ***days, weeks, months*** but can also be none
3. *no* should be a positive integer but can also be None
4. if *is_enabled* is false then *unit and no* should be None

How can I achieve this? Will I be required to create a separate models and serialize it? I am new to Django, so any kind of help/resources are appreciated. Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: What about using [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) with [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/#writing-validators) ?

Comment: @Zatigem if I use validators for the JSONField will I be able to use in the existing model without creating separate serializer for it?

Answer (score 0):

The values of the JSON suggest they are actually attributes of the work. How you arrange this in your database design is obviously debatable, whether you store all the information in the same model or create a separate model to cover the experience. That would depend on your domain. If there is a lot of common experience required (such as most require 2 years for instance) there may be an argument for a seperate model.
Personally I would probably keep it all in the same model, use generic fields and create getter methods for the values, or just serialize the model if I only wanted those values. For the below example I have set the attributes as hidden and allow you to return the JSON from a method.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

class Work(models.Model):
  id = CustomUUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,editable=False, primary_key=True)
  level = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
  is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  
  is_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False) # confusing name, I would rethink the json keys if I was you

  UNIT_CHOICES = [
    ("D", "days"),
    ("M", "months"),
    ("Y", "years")
  ]
  unit = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=UNIT_CHOICES,
    null=True,
    blank=True
  )
  unit_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

  def is_experience_required(self):
    return serialize(
      "json",
      [self],
      fields=["is_enabled", "get_unit_display", "unit_count"]
    ).data
```

If you really need the json to output with certain field names you can either manipulate the json that has been serialized, or rename the fields. Ultimately how you go about solving this problem will depend on how you are setting and retrieving the data. There is a scenario here where you just use a json field and use forms to do the data validation, or even in separate front end logic.

help with choices:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#choices

some more information on serializing
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/serialization/

Edit:

If you need to accept the data as a JSON, then either you can get the JSON from the post request

```
class WorkView(View):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = json.loads(request.POST.get("work_json"))
    #parse the dict into the various attributes
```

or have a look at the Django Rest Framework, it allows nice easy ways to serialise and parse this sort of thing with very little code.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: This was kind of helpful, but in case I want accept the data as json and not separate attributes of it what approach could be helpful?